# Postgres : can't make JSONB_PATH_EXISTS work correctly

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-12

I'm struggling with `JSONB_PATH_EXISTS` Postgres function

I'm using PG 12 and following this documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

With the following request (test it on DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d5aa984182852438c6f71cf5fa70324e) :

```
select 
    json
from (
    select '{
        "fields": {
            "foo": true,
            "number": 3,
            "listnb": [3, 4],
            "listenb2": ["3", "4"],
            "txt": "hello how are you",
            "listtxt": ["hello","how","are", "you", "3"],
            "nullval": null
        }

    }'::jsonb as json
) t
where 1=1
-- Works with 'strict'
AND JSONB_PATH_EXISTS(json -> 'fields' -> 'listtxt',  'strict $ ? (@.type() == "array")')

-- Doesn't work without 'strict'. Why ?
--AND JSONB_PATH_EXISTS(json -> 'fields' -> 'listtxt',  '$ ? (@.type() == "array")')

-- Can't add a nested condition on an array element value (syntax error)
--AND JSONB_PATH_EXISTS(json -> 'fields' -> 'listtxt',  'strict $ ? (@.type() == "array" && @[*] ? (@ == "how"))')
;
```

#1 - I can't get type() function work without `strict` mode

It could be related to the lax mode unwrapping arrays automatically, but the documentation explicitly states that it is not done when `type()` function is called :

> The lax mode facilitates matching of a JSON document structure and path expression if the JSON data does not conform to the expected schema. [...] Automatic unwrapping is not performed only when:
>
> - The path expression contains type() or size() methods that return the type and the number of elements in the array, respectively.
> - [...]

So I don't understand why we have a difference in the result

#2 I can't get the nested condition work (3rd `AND` in the sample request)

According to the examples in the documentation, the syntax looks OK but I have a syntax error that I don't understand.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Find all rows where `listtxt` is an array?

Comment: At term, I'd like to apply a different filter if the field is an array or if the field is a "plain" value.
So currently I'm playing with the different PG functions to see how I could differentiate types (looks like type() function is doing the job), but I don't understand why I can't add a nested condition after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the complete JSON value to the function, then the following works:

```
where jsonb_path_exists(json, '$ ? (@.fields.listtxt.type() == "array")')
```

However I would probably simply use `jsonb_typeof()` without a path query

```
where jsonb_typeof(json -> 'fields' -> 'listtxt') = 'array'
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, indeed it does work, but what's the logic behind it ?
doesn't work : 
`JSONB_PATH_EXISTS(json -> 'fields' -> 'listtxt',  '$ ? (@.type() == "array")')`
doesn't work : 
`JSONB_PATH_EXISTS(json,  '$.fields.listtxt ? (@.type() == "array")')`
works : 
`JSONB_PATH_EXISTS(json,  '$ ? (@.fields.listtxt.type() == "array")')`. This is really a strange behavior isn't it ?

Comment: I think if the `@` references the array, it automatically expands the elements of it, so any expression where `@` doesn't refer to the array directly will work, e.g. `'$.fields ? (@.listtxt.type() == "array")' works as well