# Postgresql JsonPath: how to identify an array?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonpath

**Update**: the comment from [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) pointing at [Postgres : can't make JSONB_PATH_EXISTS work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582854/postgres-cant-make-jsonb-path-exists-work-correctly/) clarifies the issue for me. It looks like the behaviour of `@` in a filter is to automatically expand an array, if it is referring to an array. This makes it impossible to apply the filter condition. However, there's a workaround. See the question below, then the workaround at the end.

Here is my simple test table to store json blobs:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE jstbl (id int NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'), jsval jsonb);
ALTER SEQUENCE user_id_seq OWNED BY jstbl.id;
```

My json payload represents the structure of UI layout in an app. The layout consists of containers that contain one or more widgets.

```
insert into
    jstbl (jsval)
    values('{
  "content":[
          {
            "id": "c1",
            "_type":"container",
            "data": [
              {
                "_type":"widget",
                "id":"WIDGET 1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "c2",
            "_type":"container",
            "data":[
              {
                "_type":"widget",
                "id":"WIDGET 2"
              },
              {
                "_type":"widget",
                "id":"WIDGET 3"
              }
            ]
          }
  ]
}');
```

The first element of the `content` is an object with `id` `c1`. This object has a `data` key which has type array. I can confirm this by running:

```
select
       jsonb_path_query(
           jsval,
           '$.content[0].data.type()')
from jstbl;
```

which returns:
`array`

However, when I try to use this information in a filter, it does not work:

```
select
       jsonb_path_query(
           jsval,
           '$.content[0].* ?(@.type() == "array")')
from jstbl;
```

Empty result set is returned for the above query.
Why?

**Workaround**: `'$.content[0] ?(@.*.type() == "array")'` works. In this case, it allows us to refer to first array of element, and `.*` expansion can happen in the filter so that the filter can work. using `strict` also works, which may be another solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582854/postgres-cant-make-jsonb-path-exists-work-correctly/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you!. I think my question is a duplicate, and your answer in the other question, especially your comment about @ behaviour when it references an array is what I needed. I don't know the proper way to mark a question as duplicate, but I'll update my question with details and reference to your answer/comment. Just in case this question helps someone find their way to the answer.